Randomly lagging XHR requests. Restart chrome browser helps
XHR requests sometimes take a very long time to execute. Usually they take less than a second, but there are periods of time when they lag for an extremely long time (20-30 seconds).
I notice that if I restart the browser (chrome), then the requests and the site itself start loading normally (less than a second). Also, during these lags I've tried to access the site from another browser (firefox) and everything loaded normally there. I have not yet found the reason why this happens...
There are no complex calculations on the site during the requests. I did not observe any high CPU usage or memory leaks on the server or on the client side at this time.
I'm attaching screenshots of normal loading and slow loading from dev tools chorme:
normal speed requests
lagging requests
I use nodejs and did console.log just before sending a response to test if the problem was in my server:
 //const filteredLevels = data from database...

   console.log(filteredLevels) // console.log works quickly on the server, but the browser doesn't get a response for a long time.

    return response.status(200).json({
        success: 1,
        levels: filteredLevels,
    });

But everything seems fine on the server side. The server gets data from database, puts that data in filteredLevels variable and sends a response. But on the client side the data arrives in 20-30 seconds.
I also may suspect CloudFlare, my traffic goes through their DNS and maybe they are the cause of this problem, but I don't know how to check it yet...
My outgoing traffic is about 10 MiB/s (84 Mbps). It seems alright.
Have no idea why it happens sometimes...Thanks!

CloudFlare was the reason after all: disabling the HTTP/3 protocol in CloudFlare helped to speed up the site in my case.
